# JWT Token in web api

Tags: jwt, token, webapi

While working on JWT token ,I encountered a problem ,ie, 401 JWT Token is Missing.I tried to check the api using postman [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwFnD.png)

Comment: Hi Shreya, welcome. Can you provide a little bit more context?

Answer (score 0):

You are Missing prefix for Authorization of JWT:

your Token Should start with like this "JWT you_token"

```
"Authorization": "JWT your_token"
```

Hope This will work for you